# Speeding Up Numerical Computation of Double Integral

Tags: python, numerical-methods, approximation

I am trying to speed up the following code that computes:

[image: latex]

where I only need to compute this function for x > y from 0 to 1 (but need very high discretization like dt = 0.001). I have vectorized my solution, but it still not fast enough(really need like a 10x improvement). Any ideas? (Tried something like cython, but still slow because of the nature of vectorization)

```
def solveF(x, f, lam):
    nx = len(x)
    res = np.zeros((nx, nx))
    for i in range(0, nx):
        for j in range(0, nx):
            if i > j:
                res[i][j] = f*np.exp(lam*(x[i]-x[j]))
    return res

def fastKernelCalc(f, x, dx):
    nx = len(x) 
    kappa = np.zeros((nx, nx))
    f2 = f.transpose()
    for i in range(nx):
        t1 = time.time()
        for j, xj in enumerate(x):
            kernel = 0
            if i-j>0 and j!=0:
                kernel -= sum(np.diagonal(f, offset=j-i)[0:j])*dx
                for k in range(0, j):
                    kernel += sum(f2[k][k:k+i-j]*kappa[i-j+k][k:k+i-j])*dx*dx
            kappa[i][j] = kernel
    return kappa

X = 1
dx = 0.001
nx = int(round(X/dx))+1
spatial = np.linspace(0, X, nx)
f = solveF(spatial, 5, 5)
kernel= fastKernelCalc(f, spatial, dx)
```

Comment: You need to look more into the fast primitives numpy (and scipy) expose.  For example solveF looks a lot like scipy's distance methods.

Comment: The integrands seem to be mere exponentials. If this is the case, symbolic integration is possible.

Comment: Yes, I ended up finding an algorithm for quickly calculating kernels of this form using polynomial taylor series expansion and so I used that.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was that if speed is paramount, you should probably use C or Fortran for numerical stuff. Python is great, but not fast.

Things that do pop out:

In the double loop in solveF, you could do

```
    for j in range(0,i)
```

since if j > i you do nothing. That won't save you much time because there were no calculations done, but it is something that could be improved.

Could you rewrite your equation so that you don't calculate the transpose of f? that could be computationally intensive if f is big.

I'm not a python expert, so this might be stupid, but I would avoid using "sum" and "diagonal". Sometimes (take this with a grain of salt) this generic functions have to do a lot of checks to ensure the operation can be done.

If this is of the utmost importance, and worth the effort, I would add timers at different parts of the code to time which part is the bottleneck. If there is a bottleneck.

Hope this helps.